# Graylog. Поиск лога по нескольким вхождениям в full_message

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, graylog

В Graylog пишутся логи приложения о запуске методов и передающиеся параметры.
Пример: `Вызов Method(1, "1,2,3,4,5"). IP Клиента 8.8.8.8. Время ожидания в очереди: 00:00:000. Время исполнения: 00:00:109. Полное время вызова: 00:00:109`

Вопрос:Как правильно построить поиск по нескольким вхождениям? Необходимо искать по методу и фильтровать по некоторым ID в сообщении (это `"1,2,3,4,5"`)

Что-то вроде: `full_message:"Вызов Method" AND full_message:/2+/`.
Когда я вызываю такой поиск - ничего не возвращается, хотя я уверен, что такой лог есть.

Результат достигается, если передавать ID полностью, но, соответственно, мне нужно ими играть, т.к.  они могут передаваться в разной последовательности.

`full_message:"Вызов Method" AND full_message:\"1,2,3,4,5\"` - ребатает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работает так: `full_message:"Method call" AND full_message:/.*2.*/`